# Applet not initializing because of Double.parseDouble

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, jbutton, jtextfield

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    public class Carpet extends JApplet implements ActionListener
    {
//Carpet
double length,width;

//double length,width;
double area;

//Money
double total;

double constant = 1.99;

DecimalFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
String numberInStringFormat;

//Essentials

JButton button;

JTextField [ ] Box = {
    new JTextField(),
    new JTextField()
};

JLabel [ ] Label = {
  new JLabel("Length"),
  new JLabel("Width"),
};

//Strings
String [ ] Get = {
    "getLength",
    "getWidth"
};

public void init()
{
   setLayout(null);

   //Button
   button = new JButton("Math!");
   button.setBounds(110,110,100,30);
   button.addActionListener(this);

   //Add
   add(button);
   myTexts();
   myLabels();
}

public void myTexts()
{
    //JText Sets
    for (int x=0;x<Box.length;x++)
    {
        Box[x].setBounds(50+(x*120),70,100,30);
        add(Box[x]);
    }

    //JText String
    for(int x=0;x<Get.length;x++)
    {
        Get[x]=Box[x].getText();
    }

    //String to Double
    length= Double.parseDouble(Get[0]);
    width= Double.parseDouble(Get[1]);


    //ActionListener
    for (int x=0;x<Box.length;x++)
    {
        Box[x].addActionListener(this);
    }
}

public void myLabels()
{
    //JLabels
    for (int x=0;x<Label.length;x++)
    {
        Label[x].setBounds(75+(x*120),45,100,30);
        add(Label[x]);
    }
}

public double getArea(double length, double width)
{
    area = length*width;
    return area;
}

public double getPrice(double area)
{
    total = area*constant;
    return total;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{

}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    g.drawString("Price : "+total,130,160);
}
}
```

There's no compiling error, but when i try to run my applet.

> Start: applet not initialized
>  This appears because of the 
>   //String to Double
>       length= Double.parseDouble(Get[0]);
>       width= Double.parseDouble(Get[1]);

Anybody got a solution?
Trying to make it so I can press a button and get the price out after putting my numbers in the JTextFields

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse the string "getLength" and "getWidth" You will need to create a method called getLength and getWidth.

Comment: So I tried making a new method. But I'm getting a an error now in the code.

Comment: public double getLength()
    {
        Get[0]=Box[0].getText();
        length= Double.parseDouble(Get[0]);
        return length;
    }
    
    public double getWidth()
    {
        Get[1]=Box[1].getText();
        width= Double.parseDouble(Get[1]);
        return width;
    }

Comment: getWidth() in Carpet cannot override getWidth() in java.awt.Component return type double is not compatible with int

Comment: The issue is when you are trying to parse Get[0] or Get[1] you are trying to parse the string "getLength" or "getWidth". Also change the getLength and getWidth method names if they are conflicting with Java.awt.component

Comment: My apologies, I read your code incorrectly, are there any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: Sorry new to coding, I understood changing the Method names, I did that and the error went away, but I'm confused about what you mean by parsing. Based off what I've been looking up and class, Parsing is like converting- correct me if I'm wrong. Could you please show me what the code would look like and try to explain how it works?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by exceptions being thrown, sorry for not understanding anything...

Comment: I'm asking if there are any error messages provided that may be helpful. Right now I don't see anything wrong with the original code.

Comment: The biggest issue was, in my Original code, the code itself had no errors but when I tried to run it. the Applet wouldn't initialize. Using Bluej if that matters. But after you told me to create new methods it's working now.

Comment: Is the applet initializing now?

Comment: Yeah applet is initializing properly now, thanks a lot! Now I gotta work on interacting JButtons with JTextFields.

Comment: I take it back, I added the new Methods to my init and the applet doesn't Initializing anymore. Basically the same as before.